# Configuring DNS to make a Subdomain resolve to a specific IP address

Tags: dns, a-records

I am attempting to point one of my company's subdomains directly to my server's IP address. I have created an `A` record in my DNS, and told it to point to the IP address as follows:

```
Name: access.grupomudde.com.br
TTL: 14400
Class: IN
Type: A
Registry: 0.0.0.0 (my ip)
```

However, when I try to ping `access.grupomudde.com.br`, it doesn't resolve to my IP address. It instead hits the hosting company's IP address.

What am I missing?

---

**Update**: As mentioned in the below answer - what I did was correct, it simply took time to propagate. I gave it a bit of time, and everything now resolves correctly.

Comment: grupomudde.com.br is hosted by ns1 and ns2.servidorwebfacil.com. Is that where you added the ``A`` record? Also, is 0.0.0.0 just a dummy IP that you masked out?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you set it up correctly - which it looks like you did, just make sure it's actually saved and takes effect. Sometimes certain providers take 24 hours to implement changes made in a control panel into the actual zone file. Beyond that there could be two things that would still prevent it from coming through.

- The 14400 second TTL
- DNS Cache

The 14400 TTL would need to expire before the nameserver would start propogating the record. This is because I'm sure your hosting provider has a *.grupomudde.com.br that directs to the main IP. Otherwise you would just get a message that it could not resolve access.grupomudde.com.br rather than it directing to the main IP.

On the DNS Cache your own computer caches DNS resolutions that it gets in addition to any intermediary nameservers. On Windows use `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear it out. If you're on a Linux or Mac machine, you could check directly if it went through by using `dig` to check at the nameserver directly. Use `dig @200.98.246.51 access.grupomudde.com.br`